Can recipes be improved?
I noticed recipes have a level, and some of them look "improved", similar to a piece of equipment you have improved at the blacksmith for instance: the level in the top right corner has a blue background.
Here's a level 1 recipe that does not look improved at all (level's background is dark):

A level 2 recipe that looks partially improved (level's background is partially blue):

And a level 1 recipe that looks fully improved (level's background is entirely blue):

I thought it may be related to how many times a recipe was used/cooked, but it does not seem related.
